# How to add mods in minecraft bedrock 1.14.60?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-addons

I have watched many tutorials on how install mods in minecraft, but no matter how many videos I watch and how many times I try, I can't add mods onto minecraft. I drag-and-drop minecraft mod files, I try to add them onto the storage compartment in settings, and I just download whatever says that all you have to do is download, but nothing ever happens.

Comment: Are your videos specifically on Bedrock Edition? Mod creation and installation are very different in Bedrock.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I think they are because the minecraft home screens of the videos I watched were almost identical to mine. But maybe they were on a newer version. I watched many tutorials though so at least one should have worked.

Comment: What is a platform?(sorry about me not knowing this.)

Comment: yes, I am on a pc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a website you can download addons from: http://mcpedl.com/.

1. Choose an addon:
   I chose this: https://mcpedl.com/zoom-behavior/
2. Download it.
   [image: Download]
3. If it doesn't open in media fire or it downloads directly, don't download it. It may contain viruses.
   [image: Media Fire]
4. After it downloads, open it. It will open Minecraft.
5. You will see import Started.
   [image: Import]
   It will say imported successfully(I already downloaded it so I will get failed)
6. Create a New world or an existing world then go to Add-Ons:[image]
7. Choose yours and click activate.
   You can follow the same steps for resource packs.

I hope This helps.

Comment: yezzz it worked ur da best thx a ton!!!

Comment: wait... how do I make it actually work?

Comment: what do you mean by "actually work"

Comment: never mind, sorry. I got it to work:)

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future some of the ad shorteners are safe, but if you don't know don't click it and just find a different addon

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem but it appeared to be easier than I thought. If you're downloading a file with .mcaddon extensions, you just need to open it then and then activate it in the world settings. Sometimes addons have additional requirements, for example, to turn on Experimental gameplay, like [this one](https://fmcpe.com/mods/541-lightsabers.html), due to some mods using functions that are only in beta.

Answer (score -1):

*This answer applies to Java Edition, not Bedrock. I did not notice the tag before answering.*

Most mods require [Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/) to load.

Forge is a mod loader that lets you install mods in a drag-and-drop fashion and allows for several mods to be active at once as long as they don't conflict with each other.

I haven't used it in a long time, but if it works the same as before, the installer will simply ask you where you have Minecraft installed, then do everything else for you.

After that, installing Forge mods is as simple as dropping them into the `mods` folder in you Minecraft install.

Remember that not all mods go through Forge, but other mod loaders, and some may require you to do the dirty work yourself. Always read the instructions for mods that you download.

Comment: Indeed, I sometimes forget Bedrock exists. Nevertheless, I won't delete the answer as someone may find it useful.