# How do I add a mod to my minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods

Quite a while ago, me and a friend wanted to add a lucky block mod to our world. We wanted to make a lucky block bed wars game because we had watched a few videos using that idea. We were going to build the arena ourselves, so we just needed the lucky block mod. I downloaded a lucky block mod and got a compressed zipper folder with the mod. The instructions are confusing but one thing that is clear is to have a minecraft version higher than the one bedrock has and I am wondering if you can download mods with bedrock. Please help me as it would be amazing to play lucky block bed wars.

Comment: Where are you getting the lucky block mod from? It may be irrelevant for me to mention this, but in the small chance that this may be useful, mods from Forge would only work on Java Edition. As for Bedrock Edition mods, make sure that you're getting them from a safe source to avoid potential malware.

Comment: Yes that would help, in fact I got it from Forge. Thanks @BlueTangsRock !

Comment: Oh dang! In that case, I'm happy that I was able to help you out with this @SapphireLocx .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add mods in minecraft bedrock 1.14.60?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370674/how-to-add-mods-in-minecraft-bedrock-1-14-60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must check if the add-on is for bedrock edition.  If it is a valid zip, change the extension to .mcaddon. This is a great lucky block add-on: [Download Here](https://www.vatonage.com/post/lucky-blocks).If you want to download more, this is the biggest website for add-ons and maps for bedrock: [MCPE](http://mcpedl.com) I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but your other link of MCPE didn't work. Here is the link address just in case:
http://mcpedl.com/

Comment: I don't know, but it' s working for me. Sorry, about that.