# How can I add add-ons to my game on the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I've been wanting to add some addons to my MCBE on Nintendo Switch and I'm not sure how to go about it. can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add mods in minecraft bedrock 1.14.60?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370674/how-to-add-mods-in-minecraft-bedrock-1-14-60)

Comment: not really, im on version 1.16.210

Comment: and I'm pretty sure it'll be different on how to get them on switch

Comment: @Joachim I don't believe that should be a duplicate for multiple reasons: 1. The process would be different (if even possible). 2. That question doesn't even know what an addon is and therefore isn't tagged as so

Comment: cross off reason 2, reason 1 still stands tho

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can add addons to minecraft bedrock on switch, the thing is, it's a bit complicated, and I don't have a switch so I don't know much about them, but here's a tutorial someone made:

https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-install-custom-maps-texture-packs-and-addons-for-minecraft-bedrock-for-nintendo-switch.542742/

The tutorial explains how you would add addons to your minecraft game, it essentially tells you to use your switch SD card, insterit it into your computer and then add the addons there, then adding the SD card back into the switch now with the added addons.

Comment: Basically what the tutorial is telling you to do is make a save file for minecraft, then remove the SD card on your switch and then insert that into a computer and then install the addons of you choice into the minecraft save file, then simply inserting the SD card back into your switch with the addons installed into your save file.

Comment: It should be fairly simple as long as you have a computer you can use.

Comment: ok thx for helping me